# How do I improve performance of loading a web page which shows the count retrieved by more than 35 queries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc

There is a dashboard displayed on my web page which shows different statistical data pertaining to a recruitment rally. It shows more than 35 counts which are retrieved using mysql queries. Currently it takes about 12 seconds to load the page. I tried below approaches to improve the performance but all are taking same time to load the page.

1. Using Spring MVC framework, I created 35 methods to retrieve different count data separately.
2. All queries are written in a stored Procedure and run at DB level. A Java class is written to call this stored procedure and retrieve all the counts.
3. A Separate Java class is written with single JDBC connection to retrieve all counts using mySQL queries.

Let me know a better approach to handle this scenario.

Comment: This is broad level questions can attract more opinion, can be looked from the backend perspective to have the correct indexes on the database level, It can also be looked at the way the request being accepted by the page whether it is scaled or single node.. many other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below
1. Create 35 dao methods and call them in async way in a service class. The service class could be called from controller. here I am assuming below architecture 
     Controller>Service>DAO

Here you should have a single method in controller which calls these service methods asynchronously. If you are using spring then spring has in-built support for async

Answer (score 0):

If you're making 35 calls I'd hope there's a way where you can combine this into fewer SQL queries. Failing that, make sure that you are using prepared statements to improve performance. Also you could cache the result of these queries for some time period (5-10 minutes) instead of executing them every single time; it depends how frequently your data changes.